# NSRegularExpression with french character

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

why pattern

```
[A-Z][A-z]*
```

return `Ve` for French word `Vénus` using NSRegularExpression .I want to match camel word,but this word is strange

Comment: Did you search for an answer before asking? "When specifying a range of characters, such as [a-Z] (i.e. lowercase a to upper-case z), the computer's locale settings determine the contents by the numeric ordering of the character encoding." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Comment: @Onots: It is not the case for NSRegularExpression. What you quoted is the behavior of POSIX regular expression, which is not applicable here.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks for pointing that out. So I googled and learned something today: NSRegularExpression uses the pattern syntax specified by ICU. From the ICU site: "[A-M] Range - match any character from A to M. The characters to include are determined by Unicode code point ordering".

Comment: But why "[A-Z][A-z']*" apply to "Vénus" return "Ve",not "Vé" or "Venus" or "Vénus" using NSRegularExpression

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your regex matches `Ve` and not `Vé` is because [there are two ways to represent an `é`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) in Unicode:

- Using the normalized single codepoint `U+00E9` or
- Using the "decomposed" form: `e`, followed by the combining mark `´` (`U+0065 U+0301`). Note that the latter is *not*  the actual "standalone" `´` character (`U+00B4`).

Your string is apparently encoded using the second option. Therefore `[A-z]` only matches the first half of the combined character. Since the following `´` doesn't match, the regex stops at this point. You should normalize the string first before applying a regex to it.

Furthermore, use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-z]`. Otherwise, some non-letter characters like `^` or `]` will also be matched.

Comment: No, I had not tested, I am just going to delete my answer as it was ridden with errors.

Comment: Now,I'm fully understand u after reading a post http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/ .Thx